# Caret moves to the beginning of textbox when tooltip is displayed

Tags: c#, winforms

One of our customers showed me the problem described in subject. Every textbox in our application has a tooltip: when the control is selected, user starts typing; shortly after, tooltip is displayed if user leaves the cursor over the control. At the same moment, caret is moved at the beginning of texbox control, so if the user is typing, say "hello world" it comes up with something like "rldhello wo".

I'm using a custom UserControl. Tooltip is dropped on UserControl along with a Texbox and its value is set when the UserControl is loaded and when undelying property content for Textbox changes by the following code:

```
myTooltip.ToolTipTitle = title;
myTooltip.SetToolTip(myTextbox, content);
```

When user types, undelying property displayed in Texbox is updated, causing the refresh.

Do you have any experience or suggestion about this issue?

Comment: Could you show some code? How do you set the tooltips?

Comment: So your mouse `cursor` is still present while typing in the `textbox`?

Comment: I cannot duplicate this. I created a form with a textbox and a tooltip. Everything works normally - the cursor never moves back to the beginning, even if I tab off and back on. Are you sure you don't have code that repositions the cursor?

Comment: @flindeberg added some code and context, but I'm trying to extrapolate since logic is a little more complex

Comment: If your tooltip logic is more complex, the problem might be in the complexity. Try doing a simple tooltip and see if that fixes it. Then you'll know where to troubleshoot.

Comment: Agree with Jon B.  Best bet is to make a simple one and slowly add in your complexity to see where it breaks, because I do not have this issue with a simple tooltip.

Comment: @KSdev yes, mouse cursor is present as "I beam"

Comment: @JonB as far as I can undestand, I don't have any repositioning code (e.g. .Select()). It's the caret being repositioned, not the cursor. On my machine and all the other customers there isn't any issue; it is just on one customer's one.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll build a small exe and send this to customer.

Comment: @m.bagattini The fact that this only occurs with one customer now leads me to believe it is something on their end.  Also, my mouse `cursor` disappears while I type in the `textbox`, though the `caret` is present in the `textbox`.  While the `caret` is present the `cursor` is not, therefore the event is not triggered again.  If they have both the `cursor` and `caret` that could be the issue?  Is the customer using a `touchpad` mouse from a laptop by chance?